# Comparison to FALSE is equivalent to negating value. Is it a ReSharper bug?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, typescript, resharper

I'm using ReSharper 9, and its TypeScript features. I'm writing typescript code. I have an interface like this:

```
interface Test {
  A?: boolean;
  ...
}
```

And then I write an `if` statement like this, to test if member `A` exists and exactly equals to `false`. (aka.: if it does not exist, I want to treat it as true.)

```
if (myObj.A === false) {
  ...
}
```

Then ReSharper gives me a hint about **Comparison to False is equivalent to negating value**, and if I accept the fix, it becomes

```
if (!myObj.A) {
  ...
}
```

which is clearly not equivalent, because will be true if A is not defined for example.

What have I missed? Is it really equivalent at runtime?

Comment: Not sure how Javascript/Typescript handles it but in C# the `!myObj.A` would be syntactically incorrect as it cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'.

Comment: @PiersMyers I know what you mean, but it's a completely different scenario.

Comment: I think your analysis is right. !myObj.A will behave differently to myObj.A === false. I think ReSharper is wrong.

Comment: This seems to still be an issue. I want to use a boolean field as a nullable boolean, but resharper keeps complaining if I exact compare to true and false. I guess I'll just turn that warning off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said the two comparisons aren't equivalent:

```
var myObj = {A: false};
myObj.A === false //true;
myObj = {};
myObj.A === false //false;
!myObj.A //true (not what you want)
```

So ReSharper is making an incorrect recommendation.

Comment: Thanks, I just wasn't sure in myself at the end of the workday :)